# Session variable inside a function parameter? (API CALLBACK)

Tags: php

Back story: Basically I'm trying to make a BTC api & to do this I need to basically use the ($custom inside of it) as i need to parse the variable $_SESSION['username'] onto my callback file to validate the user. I'm truly stuck here.

```
function getAddress($address, $callback, $_SESSION["username"], $secret)
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $root_url = 'https://blockchain.info/api/receive';
    $parameters = 'method=create&address=' . $address .'&callback='. urlencode($callback);
    $callback = $callback.'?custom='.$username.'&secret='.$secret;

    $response = file_get_contents($root_url . '?' . $parameters);

    $object = json_decode($response);
    return $object->input_address;
}
```

I know that I can't just put the variable $_SESSION['username'] there however, I'm not 100% sure how to do this: callback file:

```
$confirmation_level = 4;
$real_secret = 'ZzsMLGKe162CfA5EcG6j'; //Your Secret Key
$address = 'address'; //Your Bitcoin Address
$username = $_GET['custom'];
$input_address = $_GET['input_address'];

$transaction_hash = $_GET['transaction_hash'];
$input_transaction_hash = $_GET['input_transaction_hash'];
$value_in_satoshi = $_GET['value'];
$value_in_btc = $value_in_satoshi / 100000000;
//skipping to validate part
$btcpaidupdate = $odb ->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET paid=1 WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $btcpaidupdate ->execute();
```

So as you can see I'm completely stuck on how to parse the actual variable onto the callback api file.

Comment: I'm confused... what are you "parsing" and how does that involve the session array? You don't need to use `$_SESSION["username"]` as an argument if you're just calling it inside the function...

Comment: @BotskoNet This is a part of my script I'm trying to parse the session username onto the callback script api so it'll mark the user as paid

Comment: I don't think `parse` is the correct term, that means you're trying to read/extract the value from some other resource like a file. It's not clear to me what "callback file" refers to and what's your scripts. Is the `getAddress` method yours?

Comment: @BotskoNet I got it all from https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive I'm trying to make Custom $_SESSION['username'], but I mean I've tried everything. still no luck ipn works, but it isn't changing the custom

Comment: Are you trying to read data the blockchain API is sending to you, or are you trying to take session data you already have and send it to blockchain?

Comment: @BotskoNet No, the blockchain API part works, I've made a log & it works after sent etc, I'm just trying to put $_SESSION['username']; in the $_GET['custom'] parameter and using it in the callback script

Comment: What errors are you seeing then? Using a callback url like `$callback.'?custom='.$_SESSION["username"]` should provide the proper value to the callback script, as `$_GET['custom']`. What is coming back to you from the callback request?

Comment: @BotskoNet There's no errors, it just saying there is no Custom in logs.

Comment: Then you need to verify what's being sent by the API. Check your access logs to ensure the ?custom= is even set and filled with a value.

Comment: @BotskoNet It's empty no value nothing

Comment: Then you're likely providing an empty value to begin with. Debug the output of your `$_SESSION['username']` when the original callback url is generated.

Comment: @BotskoNet please check: http://pastebin.com/yyHJYcv7     it's not echoing anything.

Comment: You need to debug the full `$callback` url you're *building*. If their API is passing you empty callback values, your likely giving it empty values.

Comment: @BotskoNet How'd I do that I mean I've tried to echo getAddress($callback); & didn't work

Comment: just `var_dump($callback); exit;` inside the actual method.

Comment: @BotskoNet string(93) "bitcoin.callback.php?custom=testsound&secret=ZzsMLGKe162CfA5EcG6j" So it looks like it's working however when i use $_GET['custom'] in the bitcoin callback ipn nothing happens hmmm weird?

Comment: Does your web server access log show that the `bitcoin.callback.php?custom=testsound&secret=ZzsMLGKe162CfA5EcG6j` address is actually being hit?

Comment: @BotskoNet Apparently my API isn't working even though it worked fine 12 hours ago, isn't even ending the bitcoin to my address after sent.